# Close and then open a set (ie. $(\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A))$). Is it A?

Tags: real-analysis

In a metric space in general $(\mathcal{X},d)$. Define $\operatorname{int}(A)=\{x \in A : \ \exists \ r>0 \ $s.t. $B_r(x) \subset A\} $ as the interior points of a set and $\operatorname{cl}(A) = \partial A \cup \operatorname{int}(A)$ as the closure of a set in the usual way using the open ball $B_r(x) = \{y\in\mathcal{X}:d(x,y)<r\} $.

Suppose A is an open set. It is direct that $A\subset \operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(A))$. However I don't seem to be able to get the other way.

I was wondering, is it even true? Or do I have to be more restrictive. For example, using $(\Re^n, \vert\vert \cdot \vert\vert_2)$? In this context everything seems pretty intuitive.

Comment: You won't get equality unless $A$ is closed (because the right hand side is). For instance, if $A = (0,1)$, then $cl(int(A)) = [0,1]$

Comment: No, closure of an open set is not the set itself. As for closed counterexample, simply take $A$ to be a point.

Comment: I just edited the text, I meant $int(cl(A))$ instead of $cl(int(A))%. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Open) subsets $U$ of a metric space (or more generally a topological space) $X$ for which the equality $\mathrm{Int} ( \mathrm{cl} ( U ) ) = U$ are called *regular open* set (or sometimes *open domains*).  Not all open sets have this property; one simple example, in the real line, is $$U = ( -1 , 0 ) \cup ( 0 , 1 ).$$

For an open set to be regular open, you need to ensure that the points in $\partial U$ are not interior to the closure of the set. In metric spaces this means that for each $x \in \partial U$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $y \in B_\varepsilon ( x )$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta ( y ) \cap \mathrm{cl} ( U ) = \varnothing$, which probably doesn't help too much.

On the other hand, it is not to difficult to show that $\mathrm{Int} ( \mathrm{cl} ( A ) )$ is itself always a regular open set for any $A \subseteq X$.  (More generally, the interior of a closed set is always regular open, and all regular open sets must be of this form.)